# how to convert milliseconds,seconds,minutes,hours into days in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, milliseconds

I need to convert milliseconds,seconds,minutes,hours into days in sql server 2005. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Do you need to convert to "ideal" days (i.e. each day is exactly 24 hours long), or do you need these days to be used in the context of a particular start/end date and account for DST changes, leap seconds, etc?

Comment: A particular start/end date *and time zone*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In integer arithmetic, using the values:

```
1 second ==      1,000 milliseconds;
1 minute ==     60,000 milliseconds;
1 hour   ==  3,600,000 milliseconds;
1 day    == 86,400,000 milliseconds;
```

Convert seconds, minutes, and hours to milliseconds.

Then find integer and fractional days:

```
integral days (in units)         = total_milliseconds / 86,400,000
fractional days (in milliseconds = total_milliseconds % 86,400,000
```

And there you have it.